# ifelse in echo statement

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I have code as bellow :

```
number_format(($hasilz->harga>100000 ? $hasilz->harga+2000 : 
($hasilz->harga>300000 ? $hasilz->harga+4000 : 
($hasilz->harga>400000 ? $hasilz->harga+8000 :  
$hasilz->harga+10000))), 0, ',', '.')
```

this code result and read +2000 and +10000 only
any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what you got there (simplified):

```
if (hagara > 100000) {
  harga+2000
} else if (hagara > 300000) {
  hagara+4000
} else if (hagara > 400000) {
  hagara+8000
} else {
  hagara+10000
}
```

If you write it like this, its easy to see. `hagara` is either >100000 which results in +2000 or it is less, then it results in +10000.

In other words, the two `else if` will never be true, because if they were, the first if would already be true.

I think this is also a good example, when you should NOT use the tenary operator. It just makes it really hard to read and understand... sometimes the good old it-approach ist just the better solution. ;)

EDIT: To answer the question, you have to use a different order of the if-statements, beginning with the biggest one (or write them completely different). However, as already mentioned, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: how to do elseif in echo statement block, it's possible made in ternary operator ?

Comment: @MorhanSTambunan - If you want to keep your code readable, you don't. You do it like this example and after, you just echo `number_format($hasilz->harga, ...)`

Comment: just calculate the value and when you are finished, you echo it. This way you maintain readability. Writing everything in one line/statement is not the way to go, even if it feels cool sometimes ;)